# Notice: Undefined variable: basic html form

Tags: php, html

this is the code i am working on (it is part of this tutorial http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p9.html )

this works fine

`    
    
    A BASIC HTML FORM

```
<?PHP

if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
$username=$_POST['username'];
if($username=="ken"){
    print("you the man");
    }
    else {
        print("you are not supposed to be here");
        }
    }
    else{
        $username="";
        }

?>

</head>
<body>

<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="post" ACTION = "basicForm.php">

username: <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="<?PHP print $username;?>"NAME="username">

<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Login">

</FORM>
</body>
</html>`
```

But this does not

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>

<?PHP


if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {

$username=$_POST['username'];
$nickname=$_POST['nickname'];
if($username=='ken'and$nickname=='hawk'){
    print("you the man");
    }
    else {
        print("you are not supposed to be here");
        }
    }
    else{
        $username=""and$nickname="";
        }

?>

</head>
<body>

<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="post" ACTION = "testformken.php">

nickname: <input type="text" VALUE ="<?PHP print $nickname;?>" name="nickname" /><br />
username: <input type="text" VALUE ="<?PHP print $username;?>" name="username" />

<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Login">

</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this Notice: Undefined variable: nickname in C:\wamp\www\testformken.php on line 30 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.1800367256{main}( )..\testformken.php:0 " name="nickname" />

I have messed with a few things and if i change

```
nickname: <input type="text" VALUE ="<?PHP print $nickname;?>" name="nickname" /><br />
                      to
nickname: <input type="text" VALUE ="<?PHPprint$nickname;?>" name="nickname" /><br />
```

I do not get a the undifined variable but it does not print the nickname either
if i change the value to

```
<?PHP print $username;?>
```

enter code here i do not get the undifined variable.

Comment: If php says that variable is undefined - it is undefined. PS: What is this `$username=""and$nickname="";` ? o_O

Comment: that is supposed to make it so the text areas are blank

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're simply always printing `$nickname` on your site but you only define it in the if-block (`if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {`) is entered.

To avoid this, change your printing-part to:

```
<?php print isset($nickname) ? $nickname : ''; ?>
```

Note that I'm using the [ternary operator](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (a shorthand for if-else) here which might be new for you if you're a beginner.

To avoid XSS-attacks you also [shouldn't output variables without escaping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) in real-life usage like [Jack suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10562207/288773) (for a tutorial it's ok to stay simple).

Comment: im not sure what xss-attacks are but i am reading the link you provided

Answer (score 1):

Actually when the page loads first time it cannot find the variable "nickname", because you have created that variable in "if" condition and it can only be created when the form is submitted. 


So you have to check if the variable "nickname" is created, then assign its value to the input. You can do it as in the following code:

```
nickname: <input type="text" VALUE ="<?PHP if(isset($nickname)){ print $nickname; } ?>" name="nickname" />
```

Comment: that worked but i had to change it a bit LOL

Comment: <?PHP if(isset($nickname)) print $nickname;

Comment: i dont understand why i needed that in the nickname and not the username?

Comment: You have to do so (separately) for 'username' too.